# Where are the positive integers in the language of rings?

Tags: logic, model-theory

David Marker in his book Model Theory: An Introduction gives the following definition of a language

[image: Here's the screenshot from the book]

If in the definition of a language we have that "(i) a set of function symbols $F$ and positive integers $n_{f}$ for each $f\in F$", then where are the positive integers in the language of rings? Shouldn't the language of rings be the following set?

$L_{r}$ = $\left \{\left \{+,-, 2  \right \}, \left \{ \cdot , 2 \right \}, 0, 1  \right \}$

Comment: Arity is implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in (i), you explicitly say that $+$, $-$ and $.$ are *binary* function symbols. It gives the arity of these functions. If you really wanted to use the notation $n_f$, you could write $n_+ = n_- = n_. = 2$.

Comment: What if we had a function symbol with the 7th arity? For example, let's say we have a language $L$ with a function symbol $f$ whose arity is $7$, a relation symbol $R$ whose arity is $3$, and one constant symbol $9$. How would we write the set $L$ in this case?

Comment: You could write $n_f = 7$, $n_R=3$, but I would rather denote the constant symbol by $c$ to write $n_c = 0$.

Comment: Aaah, now I fully got it. Thank you!